# Creating a context menu

Tags: javascript, html

Been closely reading this: [How to add a custom right-click menu to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage)

And so I have 2 HTML files, and 1 JS script. I don't use JQuery at all.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title id="title">Datajuggler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "contextmenu.html");
xhr.send();

document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    // how do I draw the context menu here?
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

contextmenu.html

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So it's very simple. I pull the context menu HTML from `contextmenu.html`, and I want this div to display whenever I right-click with the mouse (contextmenu event listener). But how do I show this div in place of the default context menu?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297199/5220805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast implemented and tested this:

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title id="title">Datajuggler</title>
        <style>
            html{
              height: 100%;
            }
            body {
              min-height: 100%;
              position: relative;
            }
            #menu{
              position: absolute;   
              border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- if `body` is empty => `height: 0px` (so your click event won't be detected)
- include your script just before the `</body>` end tag
- position your menu `absolute`

**contextmenu.html:**

```
<div id="menu" style="display: none">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notes:

- hide menu (set `display:none`)

**popup.js:**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){

        // append the menu to `body`
        document.body.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;

        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

        // overwrite the right click event
        document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {      
            e.preventDefault();         
            // show the menu        
            menu.style.display = 'block';
            // set the left and top position based on mouse event coordonates
            menu.style.left = e.x + 'px';
            menu.style.top = e.y + 'px';        
        });

        // close the menu on document click
        // TODO verify if the click is in the menu boundaries
        document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            menu.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
}

// make xhr `async` request => third param `true`
xhr.open("GET", "contextmenu.html", true);
xhr.send();
```

Notes:

- open web browser console (F12) => go to javascript console and see if there are any errors
- test the application on a `http protocol` (web server), else your `xhr` won't work because of the 
  `cross origin`